# Execution failed for task ':expo-constants:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. (React-Native)

Tags: android, react-native

so, I was working on a react-native app. When i tried to add react-native-navigation using the provided documentations about it, this is the error i'm getting, have tried all the solutions already available, but not working for me.

thanks in advance!

Task :expo-constants:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
    E:\react native\rn-course\node_modules\expo-constants\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\constants\ConstantsService.java:142: error: cannot find symbol
          return info.getLongVersionCode();
                     ^
      symbol:   method getLongVersionCode()
      location: variable info of type PackageInfo
    1 error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-constants:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
340 actionable tasks: 335 executed, 5 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Comment: Hello, could you edit your question to include a little more context? (I have no idea what it's actually about but I imagine something along the lines of what code you were trying to run, or what you were trying to do/install)

Comment: thanks. edited but if any code is required i can provide thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try `npm i jetifier` or `yarn add jetifier` and then `npx jetify`. Hope it helps

Comment: thank you. now I'm getting this error
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

Comment: i have posted the new error as new question kindly checkout https://stackoverflow.com/q/59768657/12717682

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules/expo-constants/and build folder