# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Failed to execute aapt (react-native)

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am working on a react-native app. When i tried to add react-native-navigation using the provided documentations about it, this is the error i'm getting, have tried all the solutions already available, but not working for me.

```
Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.rncourse -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.rncourse -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\E:\react native\rn-course\android\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 9 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for SDK versions in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 25
```

They need to be set at 25.

It's working for me

Comment: WARNING: minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1.

Comment: Open `app/build.gradle file`

Change `buildToolsVersion` to `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"`

change `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat` to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'`

Comment: Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:processDebugResources'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'E:\react native\rn-course\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\arch\lifecycle\livedata'.

Comment: run this command `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: ok i ran the above command and did whatever you said above but ended up getting the same error again hope there is something else we could do, any help would be appreciated